# Почему не происходит прерывания по errno при посылке сигнала?

Tags: linux, c, signal

Возник вопрос, хочу по таймеру прерывать функцию и обнаруживать это по errno. Вот код:

```
...
main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alrm);
    alarm(2);
    for (;;) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            exit(0);
    }
...
}
```

Программа не выходит из main через 2сек. Почему? Или прерывание происходит, но errno не содержит EINTR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случае (бесконечный цикл) установите `errno` сами в `alrm()`.

```
void
alrm (int sig)
{
    errno = EINTR;
}
```

Обычно так устанавливается `errno` внутри системного вызова (например `read()`) при обработке сигнала, **прерывающего** выполнение системного вызова.

Прерывание видимо происходит (по крайней мере в этом коде я не вижу его маскирования), а `errno` в самом деле никто не меняет.

По умолчанию в `linux signal()` запрашивает обработку сигналов с флагом `SA_RESTART`, т.е. системный вызов не должен прерываться по сигналу. Если хотите его прерывания, то либо
вызывайте `siginterrupt(sig,1)`, либо вместо вызова `signal()` используйте вызов `sigaction()`, который позволяет задать ряд параметров обработки сигнала.

Comment: Лучше без необходимости errno не трогать ИМХО

Comment: Согласен, лучше свои флаги, тем более в многопоточной программе установка errno в обработчике сигнала может просто не сработать, т.к. у каждого потока свой errno, а обработчик может исполниться в любом из потоков.

Кстати, если уж устанавливать errno по alarm(), то ETIME мне представляется более адекватным.